# Move angular Project to another folder gave me error

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've created an angular application though angular cli, when I've moved it to another location it didn't work and I've to fix all issues I've found while running npm install, is this valid or am I missing a step, also when production this will be the case as well? ,
EDIT:
error like: module '@data' is missing

Comment: Please add more information. Error messages etc... There is nothing to go on here.

Comment: Done , post edited

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Normally, you copy all of the files EXCEPT the node_modules to the new location and then run `npm install`. That ensures that all of the packages are downloaded to the correct locations.

When building for production, use `ng build --prod`

That creates a `dist` folder with everything you need to do a simple copy to the web server.

Answer (score 0):

attempt 1
I used 'ng new newprojectname' and then merged the original SRC folder into the new SRC folder, can't compile successfully when 'ng serve' runs

attempt 2
I tried creating the project folder first, copied in the SRC folder and the e2e folder and the files in the root of the project folder.  Ran 'NPM install' .  And when I run 'ng serve' it tells me that "the serve command must be run in an angular project, but a project definition cannot be found."
ran 'ng update @angular/cli' and then got the following when running ng serve...
This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^8.0.0-beta || >=8.0.0 <9.0.0,
but Angular version 7.2.15 was found instead.

Please visit the link below to find instructions on how to update Angular.
https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/

getting closer to fixing this I hope

ran 'ng update @angular/cli @angular/core' and that got me back to where I need to be...
okay, it can 'see' the project now and tries to compile it, albeit there is an error with a promise response, I may need to update that code for v8